# What are the best tools for websocket?

Tags: node.js, websocket, erlang, go, socket.io

I have node.js for notifications in my project. I use socket.io and redis pub/sub. I like socket.io because it gives me one interface for all kind of transports (websocket, long polling and etc.) and it gives me crossbrowser client library. But I have a lot of problems with debuging code on nodejs. I have problems with cpu very often and its hard to figure out reason of it. That why I want to use tool instead of node.js maybe go or erlang but I can't find tools such as socket.io on these languages

Comment: "I have problems with cpu very often" - you mean that your nodejs code takes too much CPU/is lagging?

Comment: look into cowboy if you plan on going the erlang route. I would nevertheless check why you are having troubles with your current env

Comment: [Full disclosure: I an the CTO of Lightstreamer] If you go for Lightstreamer, you will be able to use several different client-side and server-side technologies, so that you can choose which fits your debugging needs better. You can download it from http://www.lightstreamer.com

Answer (score 3):

I worked on several node.js projects over a year or two several years ago and I find working with Go and debugging Go projects much easier. But that's as much personal taste as anything else.

There is a [socket.io package](https://github.com/googollee/go-socket.io) for Go.

If you only need data from the server to the browser I'd recommend you give Server Sent Events a try; there are several nice Go packages for that, too. For example [esource](http://godoc.org/kylelemons.net/go/esource) or [eventsource](https://github.com/donovanhide/eventsource).